# Password_verify() verifying .txt hashed string input issue

Tags: php

I am simply attempting to pull hashed data from a `.txt` file, use the `password_verify()` function to `verify` that `hashed password` matches the user's `input`. 
The hashed input pulled from the `.txt`' file and the hashed input entered by the user seem to match based on the output I get from testing however the `verification` still results `false`.

However, when I copy and paste the output of the user's `hashed password` displayed using echo statements into the hash variable `$password_test` the verification works and results in `true`.

Something is obviously making a difference when the hashed password is pulled directly from the `.txt` file into the program than when the same hashed password is just hardcoded into the program, however after testing, as displayed in the program shows, I can't figure out what the issue is.
I feel it may have something to with special formatting that the `.txt` the file is causing the `password_verify()` function not to see the `strings` as being the same, but I digress.

Any information would be great as to what may be going on.

```
$file = 'users.txt';    
        // get the form variable
        $userId = $_POST['user_signin_Id'];
        //$hashedPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

        $file_lines = file_get_contents($file);
        list($name_fromFile, $email_fromFile, $userID_fromFile, $password_fromFile) = explode(':', $file_lines);

        $trimmed_hashed_password_fromFile = rtrim($password_fromFile, ":");
        $password_test = '$2y$10$aQDNx09.73PjLmY2YgK/NuvInQPk.185vC4exOlZYgA2LiBchK6Xy';

        if(trim($userID_fromFile) == $userId && password_verify(trim($_POST['user_signin_password']), $trimmed_hashed_password_fromFile)){
            echo 'Logged in'. "<br/>";
            echo $trimmed_hashed_password_fromFile . "<br/>";
            echo $password_test;
        }// end if
        else{
            //echo crypt($password, $hashedPassword) . "<br/>"; //cryptPassword($password, $password_fromFile) .  "<br/>";
            //echo $hashedPassword;
            echo  $trimmed_hashed_password_fromFile . "<br/>";
            echo $password_test . "<br/>";

            echo gettype($trimmed_hashed_password_fromFile) . "<br/>";
            echo gettype($password_test) . "<br/>";
        }
```

I don't get any error messages to show you guys.

I expect the results to be true given the input of the entered password from the user after it is hashed using the `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` argument in the `password_hash()` function and the `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` encrypted password pulled into the application from the `.txt` file.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could it be that there's a newline at the end of the file?

Comment: I am not sure why dont u use trim() function so that all blanks spaces can be cut out?

Comment: Also have you tried by giving it echo die to check that is it actually pulling out data?

Comment: What's in your file? Why you need `rtrim($password_fromFile, ":")`? If you have `:` as last element, then your explode may be taking last element as empty

Comment: Instead of `echo $trimmed_hashed_password_fromFile` and `echo $password_test`, please try `var_dump($trimmed_hashed_password_fromFile); var_dump($password_test);` to make sure they are indeed the same.

Comment: Vilx: I will remove the newlines from the file input, to see if that could be the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Using the var_dump() function, I think I found the culprit. There is an empty space at the beginning of the hashed password input coming from the '.txt' file, that was not made a parent until using var_dump().](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQh5o.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue to the problem discovered in the above picture, I changed the following line:

**$trimmed_hashed_password_fromFile = rtrim($password_fromFile, ":");**

to:

**$trimmed_hashed_password_fromFile = ltrim($password_fromFile);**

to remove the hidden left space at the beginning of the output, instead of trying to strip any colons from the output (as they were not the issue).